# Issue with return the boolean value

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

While working with RESTful webservice in java. i cant able to return boolean value. In this code im checking for duplicate. if duplicate exist it should get out of loop. if not it should further proceed with insertion. In this case my ELSE part is working fine. But IF loop is not working with showing error This is my piece of code.

**Code**

```
    public  Boolean addCategory(String catname,String parentid)throws Exception {
            PreparedStatement pst = null;
            boolean resultdata = false;
            boolean resultdata1 = false;
            ResultSet rst=null;
            Statement st = null;
            int flag = 0;
            String sql,sql1 = null;
            try {
                con = getConnection();
                st = con.createStatement();
                sql1="select * from xxx where parent_id='"+parentid+"' and category_description='"+catname+"'";
                    System.out.println("Checks for Duplicate Catgory");
                    rst = st.executeQuery(sql1);
                    System.out.println("ResultSet"+rst);
                        if(rst!=null&&rst.next()){
                        String catname1=(String) rst.getObject("category_description");
                        System.out.println("Category description : "+catname1);
                        System.out.println("Duplicate value is trying to get inserted");
                        return resultdata1;
                    }
else{

/** Is working fine
}
```

**Console Error Report**

```
Database connection -->
Database established
Checks for Duplicate Catgory
ResultSetcom.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@1c1eceb
Category description : Test3
Duplicate value is trying to get inserted
Jan 21, 2013 10:23:23 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: On re-reading the console error report, the error occurs *after* sop "Duplicate value is trying to get inserted", so the problem might not be in this part of code.

Comment: Yes @UsmanSaleem. I want to return to method if duplicate is exist. I have tested with duplicate values. Its going through the loop and test with condition. Everything is fine, but its not returning the value

Comment: Based on your output console, it is returning the value. Double check if you have a finally block. As mentioned earlier, your stacktrace mention the code line where error is occurring. Now that you have removed it, there is no way anyone will be able to determine anything useful.

Comment: Removed earlier comment on your request. Here is the relevant part again: addCategory(ParentEntity.java:157) what is the code on line 157?

Comment: Oh. Now resultdata1 which returns the value false to Boolean addCategory(). Am i right??

Comment: Thanks friend i solved my issue. I didnt close Preparedstatement instance. Because of that i got Null pointer exception. After adding this   `finally {
    if(pst!=null){
    rst.close();
    pst.close();
    st.close();
    }
    return resultdata;
   } ` My issue was solved. Thanks for your help @UsmanSaleem spending your precious time

Comment: No issues, I will add it as an answer, you may accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check the code at addCategory(ParentEntity.java:157). If you are using any finally block, check that as well.